# Condition interpretation - Mathematics

Tags: grammar, meaning, complex-sentences

Condition is read as below:-

Where juniors who have completed their qualifying or eligibility service are being considered for promotion, their seniors would also be considered provided they are not short of the requisite qualifying or eligibility service by more than half of such qualifying or eligibility services or two years, whichever is less and have successfully completed their probation period for promotion to the next higher grade alongwith their juniors who have already completed such qualifying or eligibility service."

Now please clarify output.

If requisite qualifying or eligibility service for senior is 10 years.
How many qualifying or eligibility service is required for senior in case where juniors are considered for promotion?
i.e. 8 years or 5 years or 2 years?

Comment: it is complicated but I've given it a fling.

Answer (score 1):

they should not be short by more than two years, hence 8 years is appropriate.

let us denote "qualifying and eligibility services" collectively as requirements.

then this can be read as:
juniors having completed the requirements are considered for promotion. seniors are also considered provided they are not short of the requirements by more than half of the requirements (it means they have less of the requirements left to fulfill) or short by two years, whichever is less and have successfully completed their probation period for promotion to the next higher grade alongwith their juniors who have already completed such qualifying or eligibility service."